# add in conditional to Laravel auth

Tags: php, laravel-5

In my `users` table I have `role` field which can be filled with any of `admin`, `driver`, `petugas`, `rental`. I want to let the user with `role` either `admin` or `rental` login, other than that the login system will deny the user.

I try to override the `credentials()` method in `LoginController.php` like below

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $field = $this->field($request);

    return [
        $field => $request->get($this->username()),
        'password' => $request->get('password'),
        'role'=>['admin', 'jasa_angkutan', 'rental']
    ];
}
```

but it's not working.. I truely have no idea how to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

here's a dirty hack but at least works in my case.

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
{
    $field = $this->field($request);

    $user = \App\User::where([
        $field=>$request->get($this->username())
    ])->whereIn('role', [
        'admin', 'jasa_angkutan', 'rental'
    ])->first();

    if($user){
        return [
            $field => $request->get($this->username()),
            'password' => $request->get('password')
        ];
    }

    return [];
}
```

before pass the credentials to auth method, I, first check if the user and role match the criteria. that's it.